# Consistent user data across directories in Stormpath

Tags: java, spring-boot, stormpath

I have an application that I am securing using Stormpath. So far the basic registration/login process works great.

I have now added Social authentication, but I'm running into a problem. The way it's configured right now, it will allow two simultaneous users to be created with the same email address. I would like to have the email as my primary key for the user.

Is there a way I can have Stormpath "merge" these accounts so they are treated as one account just with multiple ways to authenticate?

Answer (score 2):

Yep! Stormpath has a feature where we can automatically link accounts between directories.

You can use the Stormpath Cloud Directory as the "master" and the social directories as "mirrors" that feed into the cloud directory. This allows you to use the cloud directory as the source of truth.

See this post for more info on how this feature works: https://stormpath.com/blog/unify-social-accounts-account-linking